# How can I progress spiritually as a Hindu?

Tags: spirituality

I don't have too much time to give as I am preparing for competitive exams and don't have enough resources to seek a Guru right now. I do jal abhishek of Lord Shiva and go to nearby temple daily every morning. I use to chant Shiva tandav strotam but I am getting it wrong. For mantras, people say don't do it without Guru. Also, I chant Hanuman chalisa because Shani dhaiya in my kundali.